# Stuck with regex

Tags: php, regex

The pattern I want to match is `[{Any text between here}]`

my regex:

```
/\[\{[\W\w]*?\}\]/
```

I am using `preg_match_all()`

It is working so far but I was wondering if there is a better solution?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse JSON. Regex is *not* a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find match that includes `[{` and `}]` then use

```
/\[\{[^}]+\}\]/
```

If you want match just inside text, then use

```
/(?<=\[\{)[^}]+(?=\}\])/
```

If text inside may contain `}` character (e.g. *[{hello}yellow}]*), then replace `[^}]+` with `.+?` in both above regex patterns. The original patterns have better performance, as they are not using lazy operator `?`.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: I am sorry, the website was asking me to wait for 7 mins and I forgot. I did it now ;)

Answer (score 2):

You might simplify it to

```
\[\{.*?\}\]
```

or even

```
\[{.*?}]
```

but other than that it looks pretty good.

---

**Edit**

Note that while the regex does what is required, the performance is sub-optimal due to the usage of a lazy operator.

When reviewed through a tool like RegexBuddy, this regex needs **21 steps** to arrive at a solution while @Ωmega's solution only requires **5 steps**.

Comment: Lazy operator hurts performance and should be omit if possible

Comment: @Ωmega - You seem to be right about performance but a comment would have sufficed. You should reserve downvotes for answers that are plain wrong.

Comment: @Ωmega - And to you  :) *(thx for removing the downvote but now I had to upvote you to make the difference between both answers noticable)*

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `(?<=\[\{)(.+?)(?=\}\])`

Answer (score 1):

*Key "U" makes regex engine not greedy:*

```
preg_match_all('_\[{.*}\]_U', '[{safda}adsfsf}}][{safda}adsfsf}}]', &$matches);
```

*gives* `$matches`*:*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [{safda}adsfsf}}]
            [1] => [{safda}adsfsf}}]
        )

)
```

Comment: OP states that he is using `preg_match_all()`, so there would be more such patterns in line. Test your code with example **[{safda}adsfsf}}][{safda}adsfsf}}]** and... it is bad :-/

Comment: Works fine - 2 matches. Your result differ?

Comment: Your fixed pattern works, but code does not. `preg_match_all` has three parameters - you forgot `$matches` as the last one :)